# Scrolling a view or an element using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a dynamic list, containing varying no. of items, being displayed based on some selection.

If the list has more than 7 items, on hovering, the list shows a scroll bar. (If there are fewer items, there will be no scroll bar.)
I have found the element of the scroll bar based on its class name but tring to scroll using webdriver fails.
Here is the code:

```
//hover
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement placesList = driver.findElement(By.id("divPlaces"));
action.moveToElement(placesList).perform();

//scroll the list
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element);
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="blk">
            <div class="smlhead">
                Places
            </div>

            <div id="divPlacesCont" class="sbarPrnt" style="height: 179.219px;">
            <div id="divPlaces" class="tilewrap sbarcont" style="height: 179px;">        

            <div class="blksmlr smlhead sngline">
                <a href="#" onclick="javascript:mcSearch.placeSelected(this, '12');">hyd</a>
            </div>
(removed 7 more items for simplicity...)

                <div class="sbar" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="sbarpos" style="height: 152.576px; top: 0px;"></div>
                </div>
             </div>
             </div>
</div>
```

Update: I got a thought to share. The list element is always visible on the left of the page (and I need not move/scroll to this element to make it visible as actions.moveToElement() does). When I hover, scroll bar within this list appears and I can click the bar, drag it down to see (last) items.

With the above code, it is moving the "frame" up i.e. everything from 'Country' to the list below move a bit up but still the last hidden item in the dynamic is not visible.

[image]

Comment: Try scrolling to the list item not the scroll element when using JavaScript

Comment: I missed a point to add. This is not represented as a standard Select or Table. The items (places) in the dynamic list have hyperlinks. On clicking these hyperlinks for places, another list of tiles is shown for each place.